# How much current travels transversely in a coil ?

Tags: electricity, induction

Excuse the the cryptic q. I was just wondering, say in a guitar pickup or AC transformer, we have a coil of copper wire that is coiled around a magnetic core(s). Current is induced in the wire by the guitar strings or the electromagnetic flux of the transfomer , my understanding is that the current travels through the copper wire around the magnetic core(s), but how much of this current is transfered to the adjacent wire(s) transversely ? 
How much insulation do the copper wires all stacked together have between themselves (of course not externally insulated copper wires) ?

Answer (score 0):

The wires are actually externally insulated, just with a very thin, often transparent insulation. If the voltage between different windings goes too high, you will break this insulation and consequently the coil.

The inductance in the coil form a parallel LC-circuit with the stray capacitance between the windings. The amount of current going through the stray capacitance depends on the parameters of the formed LC-circuit and the frequency: more capacitive current at higher frequencies.